# SQL Server pivot table to show as a row (combining two queries)

Tags: sql-server

I am using SQL Server. I created a query:

```
SELECT
    p.[accountNumber],  
    pf.fundid
FROM 
    [dbo].[Property] p
LEFT JOIN
    dbo.propertyfundassessment pf ON p.id = pf.propertyid
LEFT JOIN
    dbo.fund f ON pf.fundid = f.id
WHERE
    p.accountnumber = '238492348' AND p.taxyear = 2018
```

This shows the data as:

```
    accountNumber  fundid
--------------------------
1   238492348       1004
2   238492348       1005
3   238492348       1006
4   238492348       1007
5   238492348       1008
6   238492348       1009
7   238492348       1022
8   238492348       1339
```

I am trying to some how pivot the table in order to make the table look like this instead:

```
   accountNumber  adv1  adv2  adv3  adv4  adv5  adv6  adv7  adv8
-----------------------------------------------------------------
1   238492348     1004  1005  1006  1007  1008  1009  1022  1339
```

Can someone assist me in how I can do this with SQL Server?

I have found this:

```
SELECT *
FROM
   (SELECT ColNbr = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY accountNUmber ORDER BY fundid,accountNumber)
        ,accountNumber
        ,fundid
    FROM
      #tmpS a
   ) src PIVOT(MAX(src.fundid) FOR src.ColNbr IN(       [1]
                                           ,[2]
                                           ,[3]
                                           ,[4]
                                           ,[5]
                                           ,[6]
                                           ,[7]
                                           ,[8]
                                           ,[9]
                                           ,[10]
                                           ,[11]
                                           ,[12]
                                           ,[13]
                                           ,[14]
                                           ,[15]
                                           ,[16]
                                           ,[17]
                                           ,[18]
                                           ,[19]
                                           ,[20]
                                           ,[21]
                                           ,[22]
                                           ,[23]
                                           ,[24]
                                           ,[25]
                                           )) pvt
```

And I am trying to combine the two queries to have it do it on the fly. Instead of trying to create a `#tmpS` table.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Question: Would every `accountNumber` always have the same number of rows associated with it?  If not, and the number could vary greatly, then your expected output may not even be appropriate for your data set.

Comment: When you say you are "trying", what have you tried and what error did you get?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can combine both queries like the following:

```
;WITH StartingData AS
(
    SELECT
        [accountNumber] = p.[accountNumber],
        fundid = pf.fundid,
        FundRanking = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY p.[accountNumber] ORDER BY pf.fundid ASC) -- The order by is crucial for the pivot ordering later
    FROM 
        [dbo].[Property] p
        left join dbo.propertyfundassessment pf on p.id = pf.propertyid
        left join dbo.fund f on pf.fundid = f.id
    where 
        p.taxyear = 2018
)
SELECT
    P.accountNumber,
    P.[1],
    P.[2],
    P.[3],
    P.[4],
    P.[5],
    P.[6],
    P.[7],
    P.[8],
    P.[9],
    P.[10],
    P.[11],
    P.[12],
    P.[13],
    P.[14],
    P.[15],
    P.[16],
    P.[17],
    P.[18],
    P.[19],
    P.[20],
    P.[21],
    P.[22],
    P.[23],
    P.[24],
    P.[25]
FROM
    StartingData AS S
    PIVOT (
        MAX(S.fundid) FOR S.FundRanking IN (
            [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], 
            [11], [12], [13], [14], [15], [16], [17], [18], 
            [19], [20], [21], [22], [23], [24], [25])
    ) AS P
```

Keep in mind what Tim said, either you hard-code the number of `fundid` you will be pivoting (this example hard-codes from 1 to 25), or you will have to use dynamic SQL to generate a pivot statement that dynamically pivots up to the max amount of `fundid` you might have to a particular `accountNumber`. This will generate a column for each inicial record, by `accountNumber`.

---

To make it dynamic use the following:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#AccountFunds') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #AccountFunds

SELECT
    [accountNumber] = p.[accountNumber],
    fundid = pf.fundid,
    FundRanking = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY p.[accountNumber] ORDER BY pf.fundid ASC) -- The order by is crucial for the pivot ordering later
INTO
    #AccountFunds
FROM 
    [dbo].[Property] p
    left join dbo.propertyfundassessment pf on p.id = pf.propertyid
    left join dbo.fund f on pf.fundid = f.id
where 
    p.taxyear = 2018
    AND p.[accountNumber] = '238492348'


DECLARE @PivotValues VARCHAR(MAX) = STUFF (
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            ',' + QUOTENAME(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), A.FundRanking))
        FROM
            #AccountFunds AS A
        ORDER BY
            ',' + QUOTENAME(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), A.FundRanking)) ASC
        FOR XML
            PATH ('')
    ),
    1, 1, '')

DECLARE @SelectColumnAlias VARCHAR(MAX) = STUFF (
    (
        SELECT
            ',P.' + QUOTENAME(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), A.FundRanking)) + ' AS adv'  + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), A.FundRanking)
        FROM
            #AccountFunds AS A
        GROUP BY
            A.FundRanking
        ORDER BY
            A.FundRanking ASC
        FOR XML
            PATH ('')
    ),
    1, 1, '')

DECLARE @DynamicSQL VARCHAR(MAX) = '
    SELECT
        P.AccountNumber,
        ' + @SelectColumnAlias + '
    FROM
        #AccountFunds AS A
        PIVOT (
            MAX(A.fundid) FOR A.FundRanking IN (
            ' + @PivotValues + ')
        ) AS P '

--PRINT (@DynamicSQL) -- Use Print to check the query

EXEC (@DynamicSQL)
```

If you check the value of `@PivotValues` it's something like the following:

```
[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12],[13],[14],[15],[16],[17],[18],[19],[20],[21],[22],[23],[24],[25]
```

The value of `@SelectColumnAlias` is:

```
P.[1] AS adv1,P.[2] AS adv2,P.[3] AS adv3,P.[4] AS adv4,P.[5] AS adv5,P.[6] AS adv6,P.[7] AS adv7,P.[8] AS adv8,P.[9] AS adv9,P.[10] AS adv10,P.[11] AS adv11,P.[12] AS adv12,P.[13] AS adv13,P.[14] AS adv14,P.[15] AS adv15,P.[16] AS adv16,P.[17] AS adv17,P.[18] AS adv18,P.[19] AS adv19,P.[20] AS adv20,P.[21] AS adv21,P.[22] AS adv22,P.[23] AS adv23,P.[24] AS adv24,P.[25] AS adv25
```

And finally the full expression:

```
SELECT
        P.AccountNumber,
        P.[1] AS adv1,P.[2] AS adv2,P.[3] AS adv3,P.[4] AS adv4,P.[5] AS adv5,P.[6] AS adv6,P.[7] AS adv7,P.[8] AS adv8,P.[9] AS adv9,P.[10] AS adv10,P.[11] AS adv11,P.[12] AS adv12,P.[13] AS adv13,P.[14] AS adv14,P.[15] AS adv15,P.[16] AS adv16,P.[17] AS adv17,P.[18] AS adv18,P.[19] AS adv19,P.[20] AS adv20,P.[21] AS adv21,P.[22] AS adv22,P.[23] AS adv23,P.[24] AS adv24,P.[25] AS adv25
    FROM
        #AccountFunds AS A
        PIVOT (
            MAX(A.fundid) FOR A.FundRanking IN (
            [1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12],[13],[14],[15],[16],[17],[18],[19],[20],[21],[22],[23],[24],[25])
        ) AS P
```

Comment: If you just want to retrieve data for a particular `accountNumber`, you can filter it with an `AND p.[accountNumber] = 999` on the CTE above. The query as it is now will list all accounts numbers.

Comment: @DavidBrierton I've added the dynamic solution.

Comment: @DavidBrierton I've edited the solution. Only 2 changes: Add DISTINCT just after the SELECT when asigning the 2 variables.

Comment: @DavidBrierton sorry i forgot to change the ORDER BY. Sorry by the zig zag, i don't have the data to test.

Answer (score 2):

Try this dynamic sql

```
IF OBJECT_ID('Tempdb..#temp')IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #temp

;WITH CTE(Id,accountNumber,fundid)
AS
(
SELECT 1,238492348,1004 UNION ALL
SELECT 2,238492348,1005 UNION ALL
SELECT 3,238492348,1006 UNION ALL
SELECT 4,238492348,1007 UNION ALL
SELECT 5,238492348,1008 UNION ALL
SELECT 6,238492348,1009 UNION ALL
SELECT 7,238492348,1022 UNION ALL
SELECT 8,238492348,1339
)
SELECT * ,'adv'+CAST(ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY  (SELECT 1)) AS VARCHAR(10)) AS tcol  INTO  #temp FROM CTE


DECLARE @Columns nvarchar(max),@IsnullColumns nvarchar(max)
        ,@Sql  nvarchar(max)


SELECT @Columns= STUFF((SELECT ', '+tcol   FROM #temp FOR XML PATH ('')),1,1,'')
SELECT @IsnullColumns=STUFF((SELECT ', '+'MAX('+QUOTENAME(tcol)+') AS ' +QUOTENAME(tcol)  FROM #temp FOR XML PATH ('')),1,1,'')
SET @Sql='
SELECT accountNumber  ,'+@IsnullColumns+'
FROM
(SELECT * FROM #temp
    ) AS SRC
    PIVOT 
    (MAX(fundid) FOR tcol IN ('+@Columns+')
    ) AS PVT
    GROUP BY accountNumber'
    PRINT @Sql
    EXEC (@Sql)
```

Result

```
 accountNumber  adv1  adv2  adv3  adv4  adv5  adv6  adv7  adv8
-----------------------------------------------------------------
  238492348     1004  1005  1006  1007  1008  1009  1022  1339
```